# How to write Vector of Vector of Points in a json file?

Tags: json, jsoncpp

I am a beginner in reading/writing JSON files.
How can I write a `std::vector<std::vector<Point>>` (C++ data type) to a JSON file, such that I can access each `std::vector<point>` seperately, after reading the created JSON?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming a POD data structure, you can serialize it with:

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y;
};

Point p;
p.x = 123;
p.y = 456;

std::vector<Point> arr;
arr.push_back(p);

std::vector<std::vector<Point>> container;
container.push_back(arr);
container.push_back(arr);

Json::Value root(Json::arrayValue);
for (size_t i = 0; i != container.size(); i++)
{
    Json::Value temp(Json::arrayValue);

    for (size_t j = 0; j != container[i].size(); j++)
    {
        Json::Value obj(Json::objectValue); 
        obj["x"] = container[i][j].x;
        obj["y"] = container[i][j].y;
        temp.append(obj);
    }

    root.append(temp);
}
```

Resulting JSON is:

```
[
   [
      {
         "x" : 123.0,
         "y" : 456.0
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "x" : 123.0,
         "y" : 456.0
      }
   ]
]
```

which you can access as an array of arrays, pretty much as in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should look something like this:

```
{
  "vectorVectors" : [
    { 
      "pointVectors" : [
        { "point": "<some representation of a point>" },
        // ...
      ]
    },
    // ... 
  ]
}
```

Such that `vectorVectors` is your list of `Vectors` of `Vector<Point>`s , `pointVectors` is an individual element of that `Vector` (containing multiple `Vector<Point>`s), and `point` is the actual representation of a `Point` for you.

As for how to generate this layout, it looks like you might be able to use [rapidjson](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/wiki/UserGuide), but I'm not sure -- I've never used it.

Comment: user tagged this question with `jsoncpp`, a specific C++ JSON library

Comment: @Sga Ah, thank you. You had answered once mine had come in and it's a way better answer -- I considered deleting my answer but thought it might hold some value somewhere down the line anyway. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

@Sga's answer is correct but it missing the writing to file so I will report his code (I changed some names) with the lines to write file.

`polys` in my case is a vector of vectors of openCV `Point` objects but it does not change anything.

```
Json::Value polygons(Json::arrayValue);
std::ofstream file_id;
file_id.open(dataFileName);
Json::StyledWriter styledWriter;

for (size_t i = 0; i != polys.size(); i++)
{
    Json::Value singlePoly(Json::arrayValue);

    for (size_t j = 0; j != polys.at(i).size(); j++)
    {
        Json::Value pointSingle(Json::objectValue);
        pointSingle["x"] = polys.at(i).at(j).x;
        pointSingle["y"] = polys.at(i).at(j).y;
        singlePoly.append(pointSingle);
    }

    polygons.append(singlePoly);
}
file_id << styledWriter.write(polygons);

file_id.close();
```